# Amazon Connect Makefile help - Makefile "*** No rule to make target `all'. Stop."

Tags: amazon-web-services, makefile, amazon-connect

I'm following the instructions on the Amazon Connect Streams github to use the AWS Connect Streams: https://github.com/amazon-connect/amazon-connect-streams

When I follow the github

1. $ git clone https://github.com/aws/amazon-connect-streams
2. $ cd amazon-connect-streams
3. $ make

I receive the error:

> make: *** No rule to make target `all'.  Stop.

I've tried renaming the makefile (currently Makefile with no extension), running it as Sudo, verifying the components the Makefile is asking for are in the correct folders, and checking folder permissions.

Could anybody advise further checking I could do?

Comment: You could read the Makefile to see if there is a target called`all`, and if not, try building one of the targets that does exist

Answer (score 1):

The Makefile contains a default goal though the default goal was not specified.

The Makefile needed all: $(OUTPUT_JS) to be added.